# Is there any way to get the Uri string of a youtube video?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to send a video to a reciever. So far I have sent files like 'myfile.mp4' but now I'm trying to send a youtube video. So, I need to send the URI of it.

Comment: How are you referencing the aforementioned youtube video, if not by URL?

Answer (score 1):

Can you clarify 'send a youtube video' ?

If you have the VIDEOID and you want to send the URI just use

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEOID
```

Comment: I mean any way to get the URI with the filename not the url or the ID

Comment: They don't make that available because it breaks their ToS.